# .onClick not working with dynamic element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hope someone helps me. I have a task .onClick event fire a function with a dynamic element.
when i  fire die() function  and i have result case 2 and my variable value is katiRun = ".gn"; but after i was click on (.gn ) element it is not working and another some(".rd" or ".bl" or ".yl" ) classed element is working with function movement.

```
**1.** 
<div class="player_board_white" data-kati-count="4">
                    <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati rd" id="r1"></i></span>
                        <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati rd" id="r2"></i></span>
                        <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati rd" id="r3"></i></span>
                        <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati rd" id="r4"></i></span>
                    </div>

**2.**
 <div class="player_board_white" data-kati-count="4">
                       <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati gn" id="g1"></i></span>
                        <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati gn" id="g2"></i></span>
                        <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati gn" id="g3"></i></span>
                        <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati gn" id="g4"></i></span>
                    </div>


**3.**
<div class="player_board_white" data-kati-count="4">
             <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati bl" id="bl1"></i></span>
            <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati bl" id="bl2"></i></span>
            <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati bl" id="bl3"></i></span>
            <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati bl" id="bl4"></i></span>
              </div>

**4.**
<div class="player_board_white" data-kati-count="4">
                        <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati yl" id="y1"></i></span>
                        <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati yl" id="y2"></i></span>
                        <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati yl" id="y3"></i></span>
                        <span class="bg-circle"><i class="kati yl" id="y4"></i></span>
                    </div>
```

jquery code

```
function die() {
    if (userHasBajji == 4) {
        userHasBajji = 1;
    }
    else {
        userHasBajji++;
    }


    switch (userHasBajji) {

        case 1:
            katiRun = ".rd"
            katiStartFrom = "t14"
            katiTurnFrom = "t12"
            break;

        case 2:
            katiRun = ".gn";
            katiStartFrom = "t27";
            katiTurnFrom = "t25"
            break;

        case 3:
            katiRun = ".bl";
            katiStartFrom = "t1";
            katiTurnFrom = "t51"
            break;

        case 4:
            katiRun = ".yl";
            katiStartFrom = "t40";
            katiTurnFrom = "t38"
            break;
    }





$(document).on("click", katiRun,  function (e) {
        $thisId = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log($thisId)
        Chal($thisId, katiStartFrom, katiTurnFrom);

    });
```

when I click on the katiRun element the function effect on another element

Comment: Is the switch inside the `die()` function?

Comment: Could you add a working example and tell us the desired behavior? Where do you call `die()`? Also your JS is invalid.

Comment: Huelfe i have no working example at live server 
the die() i call on button click

$('body').on("click", "div.luu_psas", function (e) {

    pasaChal = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

    $(this).attr("data-chal-count", pasaChal);

    die()
});

Comment: It would be easier when you provide a fiddle and tell us the wanted behavior.